# Using PHPMyAdmin, all queries are run multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using PHPMyAdmin to run my database. Anytime I run a query it is often run multiple times. When I run a `SELECT` query the result is returned only once, but when ever I try to `CREATE TABLE`, I get an error saying "#1050 - Table '...' already exists", even though before running the query, it didn't exist. It basically creates it once, then creates it again resulting in an error. That parts annoying but I can live with it. The part that is killing me is when I use insert. If the PK is something I enter manually, then, like when I create a table, I get a similar result. However, if I am using `AUTO INCREMENT` and just leave it `NULL`, then I will get 2, 3, or sometimes even 4 repeated items. I don't know why it would do this. I don't think it is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar, boo) VALUES 
('ser', 'sss eee rrrr'), 
('wes', 'www eee ssss');
```

results in:

```
TABLE 'foo'
| id | bar | boo          |
|----|-----|--------------|
|  1 | ser | sss eee rrrr |
|  2 | wes | www eee ssss |
|  3 | ser | sss eee rrrr |
|  4 | wes | www eee ssss |
|  5 | ser | sss eee rrrr |
|  6 | wes | www eee ssss |
```

I think it might be a settings issue but I don't know.

Comment: Which version of PhpMyAdmin, which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Martin I don't know. I'm using XAMPP for Windows 7.0.13, but I don't know where to find the PhpMyAdmin number.

Comment: Try the PHPmyAdmin front page, there are various similar bugs across the internet, have you found any that do (or ones that specificaly don't) sound similar to your problem?